# twitter4j not included/referenced in storm-starter code

Tags: java, apache-storm

when running

```
mvn install
```

on the **storm-starter/pom.xml**, these are the first few errors which are displayed:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/ubuntu/incubator-storm-master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/spout/TwitterSampleSpout.java:[23,22] package twitter4j.conf does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ubuntu/incubator-storm-master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/spout/TwitterSampleSpout.java:[24,17] package twitter4j does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ubuntu/incubator-storm-master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/spout/TwitterSampleSpout.java:[25,17] package twitter4j does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ubuntu/incubator-storm-master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/spout/TwitterSampleSpout.java:[35,17] package twitter4j does not exist
```

i would've thought it would have been included as a dependency.  What is the proper way to resolve this?  i've had a look at the twitter4j site, and haven't found a concise setup procedure as it pertains to a maven build file.  furthermore, is the twitter dev account required to run this example?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [Storm-starter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/project.clj) project, twitter4j dependency is commented as given below :

```
(defproject storm-starter "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/jvm"]
  :test-paths ["test/jvm"]
  :resource-paths ["multilang"]
  :aot :all
  :repositories {
;;                 "twitter4j" "http://twitter4j.org/maven2"
                 }

  :dependencies [
;;                 [org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core "2.2.6-SNAPSHOT"]
;;                 [org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream "2.2.6-SNAPSHOT"]
                   [commons-collections/commons-collections "3.2.1"]
                 ]
 // remaining code........
```

Uncomment that and check. It should resolve the error.